# Maintaining persistent connections between multiple invocations of a Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am currently in the process of moving my `firebase-queue` workers to Cloud Functions for Firebase. One of the workers I have send push notifications to devices via APNS and GCM. For sending push notifications via APNS, I am using library `node-apn` in which I create a persistent connection to the APNS using

`const apnConnection = new apn.Connection(connectionOptions);`

Then I can just keep using the `apnConnection` to send push notification to devices whenever I receive a task to send one without needing to recreate it every time.

`apnConnection.pushNotification(pushNotification, device);`

I wanted to ask if such a persistent connection would hold between multiple of invocation of a Firebase Function also or would I need to create this connection and shut it down for every invocation of the Firebase Function. My Firebase Function would look something like

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const apnConnection = new apn.Connection(connectionOptions);

exports.verifyCode = functions.database.ref('/tasks/sendPushNotification/{taskId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const taskSnapshot = event.data
    if(!taskSnapshot.exists()) {
      return
    }
    const task = taskSnapshot.val()

    // Create pushNotification and device from the task

    return apnConnection.pushNotification(pushNotification, device);
  })
```

I think it comes down to whether the functions can maintain some state between invocations or are they more like AWS lambda functions which are completely stateless and since we only initialize the admin SDK once, I think it is maintaining some sort of state between invocations but I wanted to check before I move over the code.

Answer (score 1):

While most often your functions will be invoked within the same container, you cannot rely on this. Containers may be recycled or GCF might spin up extra containers in case your function gets invoked more than a single container can handle

Comment: When a new container is added to handle the extra load, does that container not execute the common code which would be `admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);    const apnConnection = new apn.Connection(connectionOptions);` in my case and maintain its own `apnConnection`?

Comment: Yes, it does that. Maybe it'll be easier to help you if you share the code you're having problems with.

Comment: I have the code in the question. My question is that is it okay to have the `const apnConnection = new apn.Connection(connectionOptions);` outside the `verifyCode` cloud function and use `apnConnection` inside the `verifyCode` function or do I need to move it inside the function and create a new connection for every invocation of the cloud function. From what I understood from your answer and comment, I think it is okay to have it outside the cloud function as the functions are run within a container which stays on and more containers may be added or removed as per load.